# Nginx - Route all requests to single script

Tags: php, nginx

I have a PHP script that handles script routing and does all sorts of fancy things. It was originally designed for Apache, but I'm trying to migrate it to nginx for a few of my boxes. Right now, I'm trying to smooth things out on a test server.

So the way the script works is that it intercepts all HTTP traffic for the directory (in Apache) using a `.htaccess` file. Here's what that looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Pretty straightforward. All requests are run through `index.php`, plain and simple.

I'm looking to mimic that behavior on nginx, but I haven't yet found a way. Anybody have any suggestions?

Here's a copy of my `nginx.conf` file at the moment. Note that it was designed for me to just try to get it working; mostly a copy/paste job.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type    text/plain;
        include         /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        server {
                listen          80;
                server_name     swingset.serverboy.net;

                access_log      /var/log/nginx/net.serverboy.swingset.access_log;
                error_log       /var/log/nginx/net.serverboy.swingset.error_log warn;

                root            /var/www/swingset;

                index           index.php index.html;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;

                location ~ \.php {
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        keepalive_timeout 0;
                        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out on my own! Yeah!

All I needed for the `location` block was:

```
location /  {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Everything else remained largely the same.

Comment: Did you try what I wrote below? Also it does mean that all of your static files will go through index.php - not sure you want that.

Comment: @Adam: yeah, I tried your code. I wanted everything to run through index.php. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 17):

Add this,

```
 location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            }
```

What it does is it first check the existence of $uri and $uri/ as real files/folders and if they don't exist will just go through /index.php (that is my setup for Zend framework where routing is done through index.php) - of course if you need to pass some parameters, just append to the /index.php a ?q= at the end and it will pass the parameters.

Make sure that the try_file directive is available from version 0.7.27 and onward.

Comment: ***Warning: This will not work on urls ending in `.php`  , for example this will work: `/doesNotExist.ph`  , but this will not work (will get 404 instead): `/doesNotExist.php`***

Comment: It would be better to use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` so query params would also be passed

Answer (score 2):

To preserve GET arguments use the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

$is_args becomes '?' if $args in not empty

Or even more simple:

```
location / {
    try_files /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: ***Warning: This will not work on urls ending in `.php`  , for example this will work: `/doesNotExist.ph`  , but this will not work (will get 404 instead): `/doesNotExist.php`***

Answer (score 1):

After setting root dir add this

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

According to your need you may change regex as you need ruling query_string to index.php

Comment: There are better ways than `if` to accomplish what he's asking. http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Answer (score 0):

One very important pitfall to be careful of when your target is a PHP file is to make sure whatever `return` / `rewrite` rule you use does not supercede the `location ~ \.php` directive. If this happens, nginx will serve your PHP file without rendering it, revealing the PHP source code. This can be catastrophic.

The safest way is already provided, `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; }`

Make sure you also set `index index.php` in your `location /` block and uncomment the `location ~ \.php` block included in the default config file.