# nginx prevent loss of POST parameters when rewriting uri

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, php-fpm, fastcgi

I would like to do some url rewriting on nginx with php-fpm.
Namely, routing all requests to php scripts to a single script like:

```
/index.php?fulluri=(originaluri)
```

Many ways to approach the problem:

[Nginx - Route all requests to single script](https://serverfault.com/questions/170605/nginx-route-all-requests-to-single-script)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735657/nginx-conf-for-url-routing

The questing is, do any of these solutions preserve POST parameters and cookies for later processing in the target index.php script?

I think `fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php?fulluri=$request_uri;` would work but i can't test as of now, would like to have some info before doing any modifications.